# Streamset Ignoring File in HDFS

Tags: streamsets

I am getting below Error while running my pipeline. Pipeline takes files from HDFS, Merges them and again stores the files on HDFS.

**Error:**

> WARN Ignoring file 'Filename and Location' in spool directory as is lesser than offset file.
> Category : SpoolDirRunnable.

Kindly let me know the possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

This file probably was already processed by this pipeline.
You can try to run the pipeline with "reset origin" option.

[image]